# Why PyInstaller doesn't detect request module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pyinstaller

I use PyInstaller to make an .exe file from my python 3 project.

The problem is this error from .exe file

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\parser\bla.py", line 25, in get_b
  File "src\parser\blabla.py", line 32, in __init__
  File "src\parser\blablabla.py", line 9, in get_b_a
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 147, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 141, in main
  File "<string>", line 57, in saving_a
  File "src\parser\bla.py", line 26, in get_a
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'exceptions'
main returned -1
```

My spec looks like this

```
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['F:\\Dropbox\\web development\\prjct', 'C:\\Users\\uzr\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\Lib\\site-packages'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=[ ('F:\\Dropbox\\web development\\prjct\\public\\thingies.txt', 'DATA') ],
             hiddenimports=["requests"],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
```

Why doesnt PyInstaller detect requests module correctly?
The request packege is 2.9.1
PyInstaller 3.1

Answer (score 2):

I can't say if it directly related to your issue, but it appears that others have had some trouble with PyInstaller and the `requests` module: https://github.com/maphew/apt/issues/45

Comment: I try to install 2.5.1,but it also fails